# Using keefox with multiple Firefox profiles?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, user-profile, keefox, keepass

I'm familiar to the use of multiple Firefox profile. However I got some issue getting Keefox to work as expected in this scenario.

### Description

Each time I start one of the profile `Keepass`/`KeePassRPC` asks me to re-authorize the `KeeFox` plug-ins.
Note that I'm syncing each profile on the same Firefox-Sync account.

**So, How to use multiple Firefox profiles, each with `keefox` addon, with keepass ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I documented it in [Keefox issue #235](https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/issues/235), you can solve as follows:

### Solution

1. Close all Firefox instances
2. Edit *profileA*: remove (use `Ctrl+x`) `KPRPCStoredKey-…` and `KPRPCUsername` in `prefs.js`:

```js
user_pref("extensions.keefox@chris.tomlinson.KPRPCStoredKey-xxxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzzz-…", "");
user_pref("extensions.keefox@chris.tomlinson.KPRPCUsername", "xxxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzzz-…");
```

3. Create only `KPRPCUsername` preference in `user.js`

```js
user_pref("extensions.keefox@chris.tomlinson.KPRPCUsername", "username");
```

where "username" is a valid GUID ([generator here](http://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx)). Here's an example:

```
user_pref("extensions.keefox@chris.tomlinson.KPRPCUsername", "693a613c-96f2-4896-871f-bcbc20de75b2");
```

4. Repeat steps `2` and `3` on *profileB* but use a different `KPRPCUsername`
5. Restart your Firefoxes and re-authorize. You should be able to see multiple authorized clients in `Keepass > KeepassRPC (Keefox) Options`

Comment: I suffer from the similar problem, but in my case I think it is caused by enabled Firefox synchronization (see my post on [Keefox forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/e6d859ba/)). What I did is that I have copied `extensions.keefox@chris.tomlinson.KPRPC*` keys in FF profile + `logins.json` and `KeePassRPC.Key.*` keys in `KeePass.config.xml`. Still the authorization dialog appears each time I restart firefox. Any further ideas?

Comment: @dma_k I drop the multiple profiles altogether. Some addons do not sync stuff which let you implement dirty syncing

Comment: The solution with `user.js` worked fine for me. Thanks!